# How to get rid of Windows 10 search web results triggered from the start menu

Tags: windows-10, windows-search, microsoft-edge, windows-10-v2004

I am trying to disable Windows 10 start menu search **web** results on Windows 10 professional v2004 slow ring preview release build 19033.1.

Here is a list of things that do not work for me:

**[DISABLE WINDOWS WEB SEARCH ON REGISTRY EDITOR]**

I've googled how to get rid of windows 10 search web results and tried the suggested registry editor hacks on:|

`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search`

- Setting `CortanaConsent` and `BingSearchEnabled` to `DWORD32`  value `0` but they are not working.

**[REWRITE ENDPOINTS]**

- I've even tried to rewrite all bing.com endpoints in windows (WTF **most of them are HTTP, not HTTPS!** Anyone can sniff those searchs on an unsecured WiFi network!) but they are restored on windows restart.

**[REMOVE EDGE AS DEFAULT APP]**

- I've tried to restrict edge in every way I could and removing it from default apps but the bastard keeps popping up every time I make a typo while trying to search/run something on my local system.

**[RESTRICT CORTANA AND EDGE USING FIREWALL RULES]**

- I've disabled windows firewall rules allowing outbound and inbound connections for Edge and Cortana. Still no effect.

Are there any other more current hacks that would work on this release?

Comment: Try not to modify any registry key, that may make start menu unusable. Try to block the executable in Windows Firewall.

Comment: This question is tagged as being applicable to 1903 but `19033.1` is an Insider Preview build for `2004`.  Are you using Windows 10 Home or Windows 10 Professional?

Comment: sorry I meant 19033.1, the insider preview build of 2004. Heck, winver is confusing ^^'

Comment: @Biswapro I have deactivated every firewall rulle allowing edge or cortana without any effect. Which rules should I add/remove to prevent windows search queries from going through?

Comment: @Ramhond, I am using Windows 10 Professional

Comment: @Biswapriyo That's a small price to pay. The start menu is a mess as it is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to completely do away with Bing search in Start and get rid of the *See web results* entry and the entries under *Search the web*, you can accomplish this even in 2004 (and possibly newer versions) by `User Configuration/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/File Explorer/Turn off display of recent search entries in the File Explorer search box` group policy or setting *DisableSearchBoxSuggestions* DWORD32 value in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer` to 1.

**Ignore the name of the policy / registry entry and actually try it** - you have to logout (or restart) afterwards to see the effect.

There are some side effects - the recent entries will be gone (also from File Explorer search), but if you want to have completely Bing-less Start menu search, this is the only way I know of in 2004.

Comment: Ignore the _name_ of the group policy / registry value and actually try it.

There are some side effects (recent entries, also in File Explorer search, will be gone), but of course search for local stuff **will** still work. In Start, _See web results_ entry and web search results under _Search the web_ will disappear, the rest will still be shown.

I'm currently running 19041.113 and have **no** Bing search results anywhere with that group policy applied.

Comment: I tried the registry edit on 19041 but it didn't work. I still see the "See web results" if I write nonsense in the start menu.

Comment: Still works on 19041.487 (for the given user)...

Comment: Still works on Windows 2004 build 19041.450

Comment: Still works on Windows 20H2 build 19042.572

Comment: In 19042.746, the group policy didn't work for me, but the registry setting (DisableSearchBoxSuggestions) did.

Comment: If you don't want to log out or restart, killing explorer.exe seems to work (if it doesn't restart automatically, you can open the Task Manager from the Ctrl-Alt-Del menu, then go to File > Run new task, and punch in `explorer`).

Answer (score 2):

So far, I only found one single way to block the search from happening, not disable it.
I tested all the ways to disable the search that worked with non-final 2004 version, but seems MS disabled those too.
The following blog post has a script that will create 2 firewall rules, for inbound and outbound connections, and it blocked the search in the Start Menu.
Although you still see the search animation going on, it will be there for ~1s and then display the following message: `Preview isn't available right now.`.

https://winaero.com/blog/disable-web-search-in-taskbar-in-windows-10-version-2004/

Answer (score -1):

Actually I found a group policy that does exactly what is asked here: Disable web search in start menu search. It is located in

```
User Configuration/Administrative Templates/Start Menu and Taskbar/Do not search Internet
```

After logging in again it is completely gone.