# How to disable Windows 10 Pro Edition searching the web when typing in the start menu

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-search

I want to disable that windows 10 pro gives me web search results when typing something into the start menu bar:
[image: this thing here]

but i could not figure out how to do that. The only working method i knew and could find online was opening the Registry-Editor,

[image]

pasting `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer` into the bar, then creating a new `DWORD` named `DisableSearchBoxSuggestions` and set it to `1`. But now windows won't let me do this anymore:
[image]
as you can see, i can't click it. (I did run the registry editor as Admin)

**Is there any working method to disable the windows search bar giving you internet search results?**

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What are the permissions on the keys.  You definitely should be able to create the key, since it's required, to disable what your looking to disable.

Comment: Be sure you are attempting to modify this key as an Administrator[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1565338/stop-suggesting-microsoft-edge-browser-in-start-menu-when-typing-internet/1565356#1565356)  There is no other method to disable the web search results[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1510739/how-to-get-rid-of-windows-10-search-web-results-triggered-from-the-start-menu). You will need to determine, the reason you don't have permissions, to the registry key in question.

Comment: Ramhound, as stated in my post I did run it as administrator. It did not work

Comment: So what are the permissions of the keys? Looking at my own computer, and the previous answers I have submitted, `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer` isn't even the correct registry key.  It also does not exist on my system.